# VNC Screen Sharing only for one display

Tags: display, remote-desktop, keynote

I have a Mac from which I make presentation (keynote).

On the main display, I have the presenter view.

On the secondary display, I have the slide displayed to the public

```
|-------------|      |----------|
|             |      | main     |
|   secondary |      |only for  |
|   public    |      |   me     |
|-------------|      |----------|
```

I would like to share the secondary display (and only this display) to a remote public using Screen Sharing or similar technology. Local public should still see the secondary monitor.

Is there a way to do this using MacOS integrated Screen Sharing tool (e.g. using command line tricks) or using another software (preferably open-source) ?

Comment: Is the secondary display physically connected to the Mac with the main display?  If so, then Keynote will do this without any third party software.  If it is not connected, are they on the same network?  What is the secondary display?  A TV, projector, other computer?

Comment: The secondary display is connected to the Mac with the main display. What is the keynote feature which does that ?
The secondary display is another computer, on the same network or a distant one.This is to allow some formee to follow the presentation with its own display (for accessibility reasons like screen zooming for visually impaired person)

Comment: On the connected one, presenter display settings can help you there.  But on the remote displays, if they are Apple devices as well, would Keynote Live work?  This is a feature in Keynote version 7 and up.  If so, I'll post an answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, but no, remote displays are not Apple devices